# Laravel detach wrong id

Tags: php, laravel, detach

I'm building a micro ecommerce in laravel, and I've a problem with detaching an element added in the cart. I'll explain: For example, if I add 4 elements in the cart, when I click "remove element" on the last element I've added in the cart, the last element is not deleted, but  vice versa is deleted the first one I've added. 
This is my Controller file in laravel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Computer;
use App\Smartphone;

class FrontController extends Controller
{

public function cart() 
{
    $computers = Computer::all();
    $smartphones = Smartphone::all();

    return view('cart',compact('computers', 'smartphones'));
}

public function computers() 
{
    $computers = Computer::all();

    return view('computers',compact('computers'));
}

public function smartphones() 
{
    $smartphones = Smartphone::all();

    return view('smartphones',compact('smartphones'));
}

public function addpc($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(!$user)
    return redirect('/login');
    $user->computers()->attach($id);
    return redirect(route('cart'));
}
public function removepc($id2)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(!$user)
    return redirect('/cart');
    $user->computers()->detach($id2);
    return redirect(route('cart'));
}

public function addsmartphone($id3)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(!$user)
    return redirect('/login');
    $user->smartphones()->attach($id3);
    return redirect(route('cart'));
}
public function removesmartphone($id4)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(!$user)
    return redirect('/cart');
    $user->smartphones()->detach($id4);
    return redirect(route('cart'));
}

}
```

This is my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/computers', 'FrontController@computers')->name('computers');

Route::post('/computers{id}/addpc','FrontController@addpc')->name('computers.addpc');

Route::post('/computers{id2}/removepc','FrontController@removepc')->name('computers.removepc');

Route::get('/smartphones', 'FrontController@smartphones')->name('smartphones');

Route::post('/smartphones{id3}/addsmartphone','FrontController@addsmartphone')->name('smartphones.addsmartphone');

Route::post('/smartphones{id4}/removesmartphone','FrontController@removesmartphone')->name('smartphones.removesmartphone');
```

This is my smartphones.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<main class="container">

<section class="row justify-content-center">

@foreach($smartphones as $smartphone)

<div class="col-12 col-md-5 my-5">

            <h4 class="card-title text-center">{{$smartphone->name}}</h4>
            <h6>{{$smartphone->description}}</h6>
            <form action="{{route('smartphones.addsmartphone',['id3'=>$smartphone->id])}}" method="POST">
            @csrf 
            <button class="btn btn-success my-1" type="submit">Add to cart!</button>
            </form>
          </div>

</div>

@endforeach

</section>

</main>

@endsection
```

This is my computers.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<main class="container">

<section class="row justify-content-center">

@foreach($computers as $computer)

<div class="col-12 col-md-5 my-5">

     <h4 class="card-title text-center">{{$computer->name}}</h4>
     <h6>{{$computer->description}}</h6>
     <form action="{{route('computers.addpc',['id'=>$computer->id])}}" method="POST">
     @csrf 
     <button class="btn btn-success my-1" type="submit">Add to cart!</button>
     </form>
     </div>

</div>

@endforeach

</section>

</main>

@endsection
```

And this is my cart.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<main class="container">

<section class="row justify-content-center">

@php
$total = 0;
@endphp

@foreach(Auth::user()->computers()->get() as $computer)

<div class="col-12 col-md-4">

<h2 class="text-center">{{$computer->name}}</h2>
<form action="{{route('computers.removepc',['id2'=>$computer->id])}}" method="POST">
@csrf 
<center><button class="btn btn-danger mb-5" type="submit">Remove</button></center>
<p class="text-center">Price: {{$computer->price}}</p>

@php
$total+= $computer->price
@endphp

</div>

@endforeach


</section>

</main>

<main class="container">

<section class="row justify-content-center">


@foreach(Auth::user()->smartphones()->get() as $smartphone)

<div class="col-12 col-md-4">

<h2 class="text-center">{{$smartphone->name}}</h2>
<form action="{{route('smartphones.removesmartphone',['id4'=>$smartphone->id])}}" method="POST">
@csrf 
<center><button class="btn btn-danger mb-5" type="submit">Remove</button></center>
<p class="text-center">Price: {{$smartphone->price}}</p>

@php
$total+= $smartphone->price
@endphp

</div>

@endforeach


</section>

</main>

<main class="container">

<section class="row justify-content-center">
<h1>Total: {{$total}} €</h1>
</section>

</main>

@endsection
```

I hope I explained myself, thanks for help!

Comment: Might not be the issue but why do you have `/computers{id2}/removepc` in your routes instead of `/computers/{id2}/removepc`. You also need to `dd()` the product id when removing to make sure you are dealing with the right product. There are couple of other issues with your code though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your forms , for every category there, inside the loop.

Comment: Solved! I'm trying to mark up in positive your answer but the system says that 'I've not enough reputation to mark up". Anyway, thanks!